# Comparing lists by reference vs value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python with version 3.2 at the moment.

Given two list variables, how do you distinguish if the variables reference the **same list** vs two separate lists with the **same values**.

For example:

```
>>> foo = [1,2,3,4]
>>> bar = foo
>>> foo.append(5)
>>> foo
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> bar
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> foo == bar
True
```

In the above, "foo" and "bar" are clearly referencing the same list. (as evidenced by appending "5" to foo and seeing that change reflected in bar as well).

Now, let's define a third list, called "other" with the same values:

```
>>> other = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> other == foo
True
```

They definitely look like the same list given the comparison operator here also returns True.  But if we modify "other", we can see that it is a different list where changes in either variable don't impact the other.

```
>>> other.append(6)
>>> other == foo
False
>>> other
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> foo
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I think it would be useful to know when two variables are aliases for each other vs. being identical in structure.  But I suspect I might be misunderstanding something else fundamental to the language.

Comment: you're looking for `is` here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [`is` operator](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in) to determine object identity:

```
>>> foo is bar
True
>>> foo is other
False
```

To quote the documentation:

> The operators `is` and `is not` test for object identity: `x is y` is true if and only if `x` and `y` are the same object. `x is not y` yields the inverse truth value.

Another way to detect if two variables refer to the same object (such as a list) is to check te return value of the [`id()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id):

```
>>> id(foo)
4432316608
>>> id(bar)
4432316608
>>> id(other)
4432420232
```

Comment: Also, if I use `for value in myList` will the `in` operator use `is` or `==`. So does the `in` operator check if the value's identity is in the list, or just if it equals it by value?

Comment: @AgentM: that's nothing to do with the `in` operator, that's a [`for ... in ...` loop statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement), which uses [iteration](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types).

Comment: Sorry, I meant: `if value in myList` not `for`. Not sure why it took me so long to realise my mistake.

Comment: @AgentM: `in` uses both `is` and `==`, (first testing for identity, as that's better for performance).